# How to upload a hex file into an Arduino Leonardo using avrdude from the command line?

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, avr, avr-gcc, avrdude

I don't like programming using the setup and loop style of the Arduino IDE. I like to use avr-gcc and avrdude directly. I have done it before with Arduino Uno (ATmega328P) with no problems, but I can't figure out how to do it with Leonardo (ATmega32u4). It's worth mentioning that I had to reset the Leonardo while uploading a sketch with the IDE, to get it to work the first time.

I have tried the following command `avrdude -c arduino -p atmega32u4 -P /dev/ttyACM0 -b1200 -u -V -U flash:w:ledtest.hex` but it didn't work.

I tried using the same command as the IDE, and added multiple `-v`, to get more information about the error: `avrdude -Cavrdude.conf -v -v -v -v -patmega32u4 -cavr109 -P/dev/ttyACM1 -b57600 -D -Uflash:w:ledtest.hex:i`

The output I got:

```
avrdude: Version 6.2
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "avrdude.conf"
         User configuration file is "/home/nabil/.avrduderc"
         User configuration file does not exist or is not a regular file, skipping

         Using Port                    : /dev/ttyACM1
         Using Programmer              : avr109
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 57600
         AVR Part                      : ATmega32U4
         Chip Erase delay              : 9000 us
         PAGEL                         : PD7
         BS2                           : PA0
         RESET disposition             : dedicated
         RETRY pulse                   : SCK
         serial program mode           : yes
         parallel program mode         : yes
         Timeout                       : 200
         StabDelay                     : 100
         CmdexeDelay                   : 25
         SyncLoops                     : 32
         ByteDelay                     : 0
         PollIndex                     : 3
         PollValue                     : 0x53
         Memory Detail                 :

                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           eeprom        65    20     4    0 no       1024    4      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           flash         65     6   128    0 yes     32768  128    256  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           efuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           calibration    0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

         Programmer Type : butterfly
         Description     : Atmel AppNote AVR109 Boot Loader

Connecting to programmer: .avrdude: Send: . [1b] 
avrdude: Send: S [53] 
avrdude: ser_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: ser_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: Send: V [56] 
avrdude: ser_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: Send: v [76] 
avrdude: ser_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
```

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04, avr-gcc for compiling, avrdude for uploading.
Arduino IDE version 1.8.3.

It is possible that the same problem can happen with Arduino Micro (or Micro Pro) because they have the same microprocessor? Although I think it is a bootloader problem.

Comment: This question is better suited for [arduino.se], which was created specifically for questions related to Arduino.

Comment: I partially agree with you partially, but thought, that since it is related to the IDE in a way and to compiler .... it will be suitable question here

Comment: Not since [arduino.se] was created. See the help center guidelines at that site. The IDE and compiler are specific to Arduino, and the site was created exactly for that purpose. When [su] was created, questions about general computer and OS use were intended to go there right away, as is the case with [arduino.se]. Once a site exists for a specific topic, it should be used for that topic.

Comment: Not a coding question so not suitable here...

Comment: `but it didn't work.` what does it mean? Be precise. Did it show the "on strike" message?

Comment: I found the tool for arduino leonardo only.
It's very simple tool, select hex file and port then click "Upload"
You can download tool "K-Up" as below.
https://m.blog.naver.com/hansin_k/220965689128

Answer (score 1):

Leonardo is a tricky board: to flash it you should

- connect it, see which port it is assigned to,
- open the port at 1200 baud and close it. As a result Leonardo goes to bootloader mode and is assigned to another port usually (but not always) with number +/- 1 from original
- flash Leonardo using the latter port

To flash arduinos from Atmel Studio I use the python code below (modified from [this topic](https://www.mikrocontroller.net/topic/388790))

```
import sys
import subprocess as sub
from time import sleep

# command line arguments are:
# first is the arduino IDE installation dir
# second is the arduino board type
# third is the .hex file
# fourth is the upload port
# fifth *** only used if Leonardo; omit otherwise *** serial port used to put leonardo into bootloader mode 

arduinoPath = sys.argv[1]
boardType = sys.argv[2]
hexFile = sys.argv[3]
port2 = sys.argv[4]

if(boardType == 'leonardo'):
   import serial
   port = sys.argv[len(sys.argv)-1]

avrconf = arduinoPath + '/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf'
avrdude = arduinoPath + '/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avrdude'
avrsize = arduinoPath + '/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-size'

boardsFile = open(arduinoPath + '/hardware/arduino/avr/boards.txt',
   'rb').readlines()

boardSettings = {}

for line in boardsFile:
    if(line.startswith(boardType)):
          # strip board name, period and \n
        setting = line.replace(boardType + '.', '', 1).strip()
        [key, sign, val] = setting.rpartition('=')
        boardSettings[key] = val

    # check program size against maximum size
p = sub.Popen([avrsize,hexFile], stdout=sub.PIPE, stderr=sub.PIPE)#, shell=True)
output, errors = p.communicate()
if errors != "":
    print 'avr-size error: ' + errors + '\n'
    exit

    print ('Progam size: ' + output.split()[7] +
    ' bytes out of max ' + boardSettings['upload.maximum_size'] + '\n')

programCommand = [avrdude,
    '-C'+avrconf,
     '-F' ,
     '-p'+boardSettings['build.mcu'] ,
     '-c'+ boardSettings['upload.protocol'] ,
     '-b' + boardSettings['upload.speed'] ,
     '-P'+port2,
     '-Uflash:w:'+hexFile+':i']

    # open and close serial port at 1200 baud. This resets the Arduino Leonardo
if(boardType == 'leonardo'):
    ser = serial.Serial(port, 1200)
    ser.close()
    sleep(4)  # give the bootloader time to start up

p = sub.Popen(programCommand, stdout=sub.PIPE, stderr=sub.PIPE)#, shell=True)
output, errors = p.communicate()
# avrdude only uses stderr, append it
print errors
```

Comment: Will give it a try and I'll accept your answer if I find it working. (Thanks for taking time to answer this)

Comment: This is the way to go! I wrote a bash script based on it: [tsk/upload](https://github.com/gibatronic/sesame/blob/master/tsk/upload). Thanks @gryphon!

Answer (score 0):

Gryphon's solution often, but not always, works. The Leonardo has a bootloader that can be used for programming the flash, but it can also skip that and jump straight to the user program. Here's how it decides what it does:

- If it boots up after an external reset (meaning the reset button was pressed), it will always go to programming mode.
- If there is no program in the flash (the first word is 0xffff), it will always go to programming mode.
- If it boots up after a power-on reset (meaning the device wakes up for the first time after power is applied to VCC), it will try to run the user code.
- If it boots up after a watchdog reset, then:

  - If there is a magic code written to a magic location in SRAM (0x7777 written to 0x0800), then it will go to programming mode.
  - Otherwise it will try to run user code.
- If it boots up after any other reset, it will go to programming mode.

The 1200 baud trick uses the watchdog feature: if the current user code contains a serial port from the Arduino libraries, it contains code to do that: if the port is closed after it was set to a speed of 1200 baud, the library code writes the magic word to SRAM and enables the watchdog so it will reset the microcontroller. The boot loader will understand this as a request to go into programming mode.

However, the trick doesn't always work: if the user code does not bring up a serial port, it will never respond. The same is true when something is wrong with the user code and the USB system doesn't activate. So while it is an interesting method for flashing, there's a good chance that it will not work.

The more robust solution is to use the external reset: if you press the reset button, the user code is not involved and the bootloader will always go into programming mode. If your board does not have a hardware reset button, you will want to connect one. It is the only guaranteed way to access the bootloader (without resorting to JTAG or ICSP).

Note that the bootloader has an 8 second timeout: if programming has not started 8 seconds after it is entered (through any method), it will try to run the user code.

Answer (score -2):

1. If you have grown from the arduine style programming - forget about arduino IDE, bootloaders and all the stuff around it.
2. Buy an USB ASP programmer from ebay or aliexpress. You can also use your arduino board program another - https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoISP
3. Install ATMEL studio or eclipse + AVR toolchain + pluginns
4. Enjoy more decent IDEs, start programming :)

Comment: my question is not about how to adopt another IDE, I'm using vim for development.  And I want to program a leonardo (µC can't be removed) like I specified in the details of the question.

Comment: so you can ignore point 3 and 4 except enjoying. It is pointless to keep this bootloader is you do not program it as arduino.

Comment: This is ignorant and just plain wrong.  There is no actual linkage between using an Arduino approach, and using the bootloader.  You can use the bootloader with non-Arduino programs (indeed it predates Arduino usage of the chip and originates outside the Arduino world), and you can load Arduino programs with an ISP programmer (even right in the IDE).  The two are **fully independent**.